# Fullname field not being validated without using submit button

Tags: jquery, validation

I am working on a jQuery validation for a form fields

I cannot seem to get the following to work :

1. My `Full Name` field needs to be like : `roger federer` or `roger-federer` (currently validation is accepting a single word too, which shouldn't be allowed.
2. I do not need to have a `submit` button, but, for now, I have just kept it, in order to make it work temporarily.

Could someone tell me how to achieve validation without having the `submit` button?

Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>

<script type="text/javascript"   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-joshbush.googlecode.com/files/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.1.pack.js"></script>


     <script>

            $(document).ready(function() {

                var validCharactersRegex = new RegExp(/^[a-z -]+$/);
                var doesNotStartWithDashOrSpace = new RegExp(/^[^ -]/);
                var fullname_invalid = function(value) {
                    return validCharactersRegex.test(value) && doesNotStartWithDashOrSpace.test(value) && value.indexOf('  ') == -1 && value.indexOf('--') == -1 && value.indexOf(' -') == -1 && value.indexOf('- ') == -1;
                }


                $.validator.addMethod("custom_fullname", function(value, element) {
                    return fullname_invalid(value);
                }, 'Your Name should be entered like: "blahblah"');

                $('#signup').validate({
                    rules: {
                        fullname: {
                            required: true,
                            custom_fullname: true
                        },                  
                        email: {
                          required: true,
                          email: true
                        }
                    },


                    messages: {
                        fullname : {
                          required: "Please specify your Full Name",             
                          custom_fullname : "Your Name should be entered like: fullname lastname  (or) fullname-lastname"
                        },
                        email: {
                          required: "We need your email address to contact you",
                          email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
                        }
                    }


                });

                $('#signup').on('submit', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                });


             $("#phone").mask("(9999) 9999999");

            });

              </script> 


        <style>
                .error {color: red;}
        </style>


 </head>




 <body>

    <form id="signup" action="/action">

        Full Name: <input name="fullname" type="text"  maxlength="14" /><br/>
        Email <input id="email" name="email" size="25"  class="required email" /><br/>
        Telephone Number: <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" /><br/>

        <input type="submit">

    </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi...Yes u can submit the form without SUBMIT button..But u must be clear when to submit...On any event like button click, keydown?

Comment: Actually in my case I do not need to use any form tag, or any submit button , (in short, i do not need to submit at all) iam thinking to have  a validation of any field as 'omblur', so howz that possible...

Comment: Yes.. U can make that too...Check this example http://jsfiddle.net/GXNKf/

Comment: @AyyappanSekar  Actually iam not aware of much jquery , could you please make my above code work without using submit button. I will be glad if you would help me on this..

Comment: I do not know about jQuery validation... Are u ok if i use just the basic jQuery?

Comment: @AyyappanSekar : Can you able to make me achive this using above code only:  My Full Name field needs to be like : roger federer or roger-federer (currently validation is accepting a single word too, which shouldn't be allowed. ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21119/discussion-between-ayyappan-sekar-and-clarsen)

Answer (score 0):

Hi hope the solution will help u... I suggest to submit ur form on blur of phone field...

```
<html>
 <head>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-joshbush.googlecode.com/files/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.1.pack.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#fullname").bind('blur', function(){
                var name = $("#fullname").val();  
                if(!name.match(/^[a-z -]+$/) || name.indexOf('-')==0 || name.indexOf(' ')==0 || 
                (name.split('-').length<2 && name.split(' ').length<2)) {
                    alert('name must be like roger federer or roger-federer');
                    return false;
                }
            });
            $("#phone").bind('blur', function (){
                 //submit ur form here
                 //$('#signup').submit();    
             });
        });

    </script>
    <style>
                    .error {color: red;}
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <form id="signup" action="/action">
        Full Name: <input id="fullname" name="fullname" type="text"  maxlength="14" /><br/>
        Email <input id="email" name="email" size="25"  class="required email" /><br/>
        Telephone Number: <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" /><br/>
    </form>
 </body>
</html>
```